# How to convert string to byte in Python, and add the values in the byte?

Tags: python, byte

I am using Python 2.7.

I was given the docstring to this function:

```
def test(a, b):
    ''' takes two bytes, returns the the bytes when the two bytes are added up
    (bytes, bytes) -> bytes
    j = 0
    k = j + b[0]
```

I tried doing this (which i was told would be a valid input to the function and follows the docstring):

```
test(b"2402", b"testing"):
```

but this raises an error saying

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

From my understanding, bytes consist of 1's and 0's (i.e. integers). So shouldn't I be able to add each index of the byte?

Example: `test(b"123", b"testing")` a and b will be bytes (consisting of 1's and 0's). I should be able to add the numbers, let it equal x, and return b"x".

Edit: The function itself does not need to be solved, I just made it up to use an example to show what I want. I just want to know how to convert a string to a byte in Python 2.7.

Comment: "Don't bytes consist of 1's and 0's? So shouldn't I be able to add them?" No, that doesn't follow at all. *Everything* on a typical modern machine fundamentally consist of bits, but that doesn't mean you can add things together. Anyway, it is unclear to me the result you are expecting. Can you give an example? Also, are you on Python 2?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `test(11111111, 11111111)` should return `22222222` translated into a byte, i.e. `b"22222222"`)

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Your docstring implies that the function accepts two `bytes` objects, but you now have it accepting two `int` objects. Which is it?

Comment: @georgexsh No.. it's me asking how to get a byte from a string in Python 2.7 ............

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My mistake, I meant `11111111` to be a byte when I was giving an example. Basically, given two bytes `a` and `b` `test(b"testing", b"123")`, we know `a` and `b` are bytes (i.e. consisting of 1's and 0's), I want to add the 1's and 0's of `a` and `b` and let it equal `x`. Then, I want to output `b"x"`). I basically just want to know how to convert a string to a byte in Python 2.7, the function is just an example I came up with to show what I want.

Comment: to my knowledge there is no defined rule for converting string to "byte", you need clarify a rule.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using python 2, use

```
bytearray("2402")
```

or

```
"2402".encode('utf-8')
```

try this if you decide to switch to python 3.x:

```
test(bytes("2402", 'utf-8'), bytes("testing", 'utf-8'))
```

to covert string to bytes or bytes to string you should provide encoding
also if you have bytes, you cannot get correct result with str, but you should use encoding as follows:

```
b"abcde".decode("utf-8")
```

You should consider another thing that indexing on bytes will not return a byte, instead is returning integer
try this:

```
>>>type(b[0])
<class 'int'>
```

because bytes and bytearray objects are sequences of integers (between 0 and 255)

Comment: I get a `TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)` when I do `bytes("testing", 'utf-8')` or `bytes("2402", 'utf-8')`

Comment: As you are using python 2, use bytearray("2402") or "2402".encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

that function works in python3, because in py3, for a bytes object `b`, `b[0]` will be an int:

```
>>> type(b'abc'[0])
<class 'int'>
```

but as you are using python2, `b[0]` will be a str:

```
>>> type(b'abc'[0])
<type 'str'>
```

add str and int together is not allowed.

Comment: if you are using python3 interpreter, is should works.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, I want to make it work for 2.7

Comment: what do you mean 'it'?

Comment: given a string, how do I convert it into a byte and access the byte. ie. given b"testing", I want to see how it looks when it is a byte. (using python 3, we can see that b"testing" as a byte is 116101115116105110103

Comment: see `ord` or `array.fromstring`, your question is not the same as a I answered it.